# Babel / Webpack: Cannot find "yaml-loader" (works in development, not production)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

Here's the offending line of code:

```
import Channel from '!json-loader!yaml-loader!../../../../config/channel.yml'
```

As you can see, I'm using `!`s to bypass the normal import loader logic so I can import the parsed YAML file as a local variable at compile-time.

This works perfectly in development (with webpack-dev-server) but fails in production:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'yaml-loader' in '/var/www/www.avfacts.org/releases/20180205125420/app/frontend/views/Episodes'
 @ /var/www/www.avfacts.org/shared/node_modules/babel-loader/lib!/var/www/www.avfacts.org/shared/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/frontend/views/Episodes/Form.vue 87:0-78
 @ ./app/frontend/views/Episodes/Form.vue
 @ /var/www/www.avfacts.org/shared/node_modules/babel-loader/lib!/var/www/www.avfacts.org/shared/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/frontend/views/Episodes/Edit.vue
 @ ./app/frontend/views/Episodes/Edit.vue
 @ ./app/frontend/routes.js
 @ ./app/frontend/packs/application.js
```

Here's my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "avfacts",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@panter/vue-i18next": "^0.9.1",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^3.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-minify": "^0.2.0",
    "i18next": "^10.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "luxon": "^0.4.0",
    "marked": "^0.3.12",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.2.1",
    "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "precss": "^3.1.0",
    "simplemde": "^1.11.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.13",
    "vue-datetime": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.7.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.13",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "weekstart": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1",
    "yaml-loader": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

(and yes, I did try moving `yaml-loaders` from `devDependencies` to `dependencies` even though that shouldn't work, and it did indeed not work)

Answer (score 1):

Have you added loader in your webpack.config.js .

// webpack.config.js

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.yaml$/,
      include: path.resolve('data'),
      loader: 'yaml',
    },
  ],
}
```

As its been mentioned in https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml-loader

Comment: Thanks, I did try that, and it didn't change anything. My understanding of using the inline loader syntax (`import foo from '!loader-name!path/to/file'`) is that it doesn't matter whether or not it's in your loader config anyway, I think.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Nope, that wasn't it. I replaced yaml-loader with yaml-js-loader and called it a day. Still not sure what the problem was.

This problem was seemingly fixed by disabling `require 'capistrano/rails/assets` in my `Capfile`, thus disabling the normal Rails Sprockets asset compilation (this task also runs `yarn install`, but apparently in a different environment or something?).

Now only the `capistrano/yarn` tasks run, which perform the Webpack asset compilation successfully.